# Basic mod_rewrite issue -> mysite.us/user/xyz.php to mysite.us/user/index.php?u=xyz

Tags: regex, url, mod-rewrite

I'm trying out mod_rewrite for the first time and not having much luck so far. My current URL is in the format of `http://mywebsite.com/user/index.php?u=123`. How can I rewrite the URL to be `http://mywebsite.com/user/123`?

So far, I've (unsuccessfully) tried the following, which resulted in 500 Internal Server Errors

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user([^/]*)\.php$ /user/index.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Where am I going wrong? This should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You very nearly had it correct. Rather than `[^/]` matching everything up to but not including the next `/`, you want `([\d]+)$` matching all digits until the end.  You'll need a `/` after `user`, and finally, remove the `.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([\d]+)$ /user/index.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Note, I also removed the leading `/` on the right-side rewrite from `/user`. That may not have been necessary though; I can never remember how it behaves with the leading `/` unless I test for myself.

Most likely, the cause of your 500 error was a rewrite loop. Since you were matching .php on the end, even `user/index.php` would match the rule, throwing it into an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 on the `http://mysite.us/user/123` page after adding this to the `.htaccess` file. The other url (`http://mysite.us/user/index.php?u=123`) still serves the page as it should.

Comment: @acedanger Then try replacing the leading `/` where I removed it at `/user/index.php`

Comment: @acedanger Change to `[L,R]` so it does an actual redirect and you can see what URL it's ultimately hitting. This is odd, I'd expect it to work.  You have the .htaccess at the root, right? not in the user/ directory?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but my site has WordPress on it. Here are the contents of my `.htaccess` file:

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/user/([\d]+)$ user/index.php?u=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

Comment: Some of that does matter.  Move the new rule above the `. index.php [L]` rule.  Also, that leading `/` goes on the right side (rewritten), not the left input side. See above.

Comment: When I add the `RewriteRule ^user/([\d]+)$ /user/index.php?u=$1 [L, R]` to the `.htaccess` file, I start getting the 500 internal server errors. The `.htaccess` file is in the root of the webpage.

Comment: But what is the URL that ends up in the address bar when you have the `[R]` flag in there? It should get redirected somewhere.  Generally you have to debug rewrite rules by commenting out all previous `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`

Comment: I believe I've got it sorted out. For whatever reason, when I added the `[L, R]`, that's when the internal server errors showed up. I removed the `R` and left the line where you told me in one of your comments above.

Comment: Thank you for working with me on this @Michael. I really appreciate it and it would have taken me ages to get this sorted out on my own. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck to you.